# WSAGetLastError() returns negative value after Sendto() fails

Tags: sockets, winapi, udp

UDP socket occasionally fails when trying to use Sendto(). I catch the error code with WSAGetLastError(), but the value it returns is negative. The list of WSAGetLastError errors do not list anything negative.

```
if (sendto(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &si_sender, si_senderSize) == -1)
{
    int e = WSAGetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %d\n", e);
}
```

I get error: -1073741251

So what is going on here?

Comment: Always convert weirdo large negative error codes to hex.  That gets you 0xc000023d.  Error codes like that are documented in the ntstatus.h SDK header.  It is STATUS_HOST_UNREACHABLE, "The remote system is not reachable by transport".  That happens.

Comment: @HansPassant "Always convert weirdo large negative error codes to hex." Thank you for that info, now I know what to do with them. Why was the definition for this error in ntstatus.h and not part of the WSAGetLastError list of errors? Also, this occurs almost always after I rebind the adapter to refresh new network settings. I have the program sleep for 3 seconds while the new settings are refreshed. I wonder if that has something to do with the failed Sendto()?

Comment: `WSAGetLastError()` is just a thunk that redirects to `GetLastError()`. So in theory, *any* Win32 error code can be reported by any failed socket operation. What I would be more concerned about is that `sendto()` is reporting `STATUS_HOST_UNREACHABLE` instead of `WSAEHOSTUNREACH` when setting the error code in the first place. That is either a bug in `sendto()`, or more likely `sendto()` is internally delegating to another layer that itself is setting the actual error code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, that is very weird. Looking at Winsock.c, I saw the following when making a call to WSAGetLastError(): case STATUS_HOST_UNREACHABLE: return WSAEHOSTUNREACH; Is there anything on my side of things I can do about this? The intermittent problem is very annoying.